# Replacing default phone application with other one on rooted device

Tags: root-access, system-apps, customization

I'm on Android 4.1, rooted, with ClockworkMod Recovery. I want to replace the default `phone.apk` in root with my custom downloaded APK, and cumbersome is my default `phone.apk` that is shipped with my custom ROM.

Can I replace my `phone.apk` from the system/app with a new Phone application such as Swipe Dialer Pro? Will it do any harm?

There is also one additional APK in the system/app called `phone service.apk`. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: Why do you want to install the new phone app to `/system`? You can use a new phone app by installing it in the usual way.

Comment: Its cumbersome on my custom rom

Comment: I just want to remove it and replace with other one

Comment: How is simply installing an app from the Play Store "cumbersome"?

Comment: I want to replace the default phone.apk in root to my cudtom downliaded apk.and cumbersome is my default phone.apk that is shipped with my custom rom

Comment: So does copy/paste not work? Why bother replacing it? Why not install a better dialler side loading or via the play store and then set it as the default? I don't understand the issue here? Be aware that the new dialler is built into Google Search also so you will need (if you want that one) the phone apk, the correct Google Services apk and the correct google search apk... or you could just install things as normal..?

Comment: Ok thanks RossC i will not take the risk doing that. Just install as normal ok.

Comment: @user52165 yep I think that is safest. It depends on what dialer you want, and IN THEORY you'd be fine, but from my own (limited) experience it can all go wrong quite fast. Diallers are small apps so best install normally. You can't install the Kitkat dialer anyway, as you are on 4.1!

Comment: I waa trying to put swipe dialer pro

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way I found. Just download some system app installer APK and install it. Then get `phone.apk` and `contact.apk` from any custom ROM which is for your device and install them using the system app installer. That's all you can do

I've tried a lot to find the way, but it didn't work. Good luck.